# Simplecart checkout by email not working

Tags: javascript, php, simplecart

I am working with simplecart and I wish to send the order to my email. Im not getting an email now and I don't know how to solve this. Any help would be appreciated!

This is my simpleCart.js

```
me.emailCheckout = function() {    


itemsString = "";
for( var current in me.items ){ 
    var item = me.items[current];
    itemsString += item.quantity + " st\n" + item.name + "\n Pris: " + item.price + " kr/st \n\n";
}


var namn=document.getElementById('namn').value; var filter = /^[A-Za-z0-9 ]{3,35}$/;
if (!filter.test(namn))
{
//window.location = "popup.html";
window.alert("Du m&aring;ste ange namn!");
namn.focus; return true;
}

var telefon=document.getElementById('telefon').value; var filter =  /^\d{10}$/;
if (!filter.test(telefon))
{
//window.location = "popup_tel.html";
window.alert("Du m&aring;ste ange ett korrekt telefonnummer!");
telefon.focus; return true;
}

var namn = document.form.namn.value;
var telefon = document.form.telefon.value;

for (var i=0; i < document.form.betalning.length; i++)
 {
if (document.form.betalning[i].checked)
  {
  var betalning = document.form.betalning[i].value;
  }
 }

var adress = document.getElementById("adress").value;
var ovrigt = document.getElementById("ovrigt").value;
leverans = "";
for (var i=0; i < document.form.leverans.length; i++)
 {
if (document.form.leverans[i].checked)
  {
  var leverans = document.form.leverans[i].value;
  }
 }          

me.total += "" + " KR"

var form = document.createElement("form");
form.style.display = "none";
form.method = "POST";
form.action = "ordered.php";
form.acceptCharset = "UTF-8";
form.appendChild(me.createHiddenElement("jcitems", itemsString));
form.appendChild(me.createHiddenElement("jctotal", me.total));
form.appendChild(me.createHiddenElement("namn", namn));
form.appendChild(me.createHiddenElement("telefon", telefon));
form.appendChild(me.createHiddenElement("adress", adress));
form.appendChild(me.createHiddenElement("leverans", leverans));
form.appendChild(me.createHiddenElement("betalning", betalning));
form.appendChild(me.createHiddenElement("ovrigt", ovrigt));
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
document.body.removeChild(form);


};
```

And this would send the form to ordered.php

```
<?php

        $to  = 'mymail@mail.com'; 


        $subject = 'ORDER';
        $jcitems = $_POST['jcitems'] .
         " \n\n SUMMA: " . $_POST['jctotal'] .
         " \n\n-------------------------------\n " .
         " \n KUNDINFORMATION:\n " .
         " \n Namn:\n " . $_POST['namn'] .
         " \n\n Telefon:\n " . $_POST['telefon'] .
         " \n\n Hemkörning:\n " . $_POST['leverans'] .
         " \n\n Betalar med:\n " . $_POST['betalning'] .
         " \n\n Adress:\n " . $_POST['adress'] .
         " \n\n Övrigt:\n " . $_POST['ovrigt'] .

         " \n\n\n IP: " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] .
         " \n\n" . date("Y-m-d") .
         " \n" . date("H:i:s") . 
         " \n\n -" ;

        $headers = 'From: Bestallning@Pizzeria' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: Mobil@Pizzeria' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

     mail($to, $subject, $jcitems, $headers);
    /*Clearing the cart info after succesfull order is made*/
     setcookie ("simpleCart", "", time() - 3600);

   //header('Location: ordered.php');

                            ?>
```

Comment: where are you calling the function that sends the email?

Comment: I solved this problem by including swift mail instead of using the basic mail function in php.